# Slot Machine in Java

Tags: java

I am supposed to build a slot machine that has 3 display windows, each window has 6 options that could display.

I am confused what "test expression" to use after the term switch? and then how to get the program to compare the 6 cases or options (cherry, orange, plum, bell, melon, bar) to see if they match and offer a return of what they won.

```
    import java.util.Random;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class SlotMachine
    {
       //This is the main method
         public static void main(String[] args)
      {
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       Random random = new Random();
       String cont = "y" or "Y";
       char answer;
       int money = 0;
       int totalEntered = 0;
       int a;
       int n;
       int amountWon = 0;
       int dbl = money * 2;
       int trpl = money * 3;

       while (cont.equals("y"))OR (cont.equals("Y"))
       {
           a = random.nextInt(6);
           n = random.nextInt(991) +10;
           totalEntered += money;
           System.out.println("How much money would you like to bet? ");
           money = keyboard.nextInt();

           switch (TestExpression????) 
           {
               case 0:
                   System.out.println("Cherry");
                   break;
               case 1:
                   System.out.println("Orange");
                   break;
               case 2:
                   System.out.println("Plum");
                   break;
               case 3:
                   System.out.println("Bell");
                   break;
               case 4:
                   System.out.println("Melon");
                   break;
               default:
                   System.out.println("Bar");
           }

           if ()
           {
               System.out.println("You have won $0");
           }
           else if ()
           {
               System.out.println("Congratulations, you have won $" + dbl);
                  amountWon += dbl;
           }
           else if ()
           {
               System.out.println("Congratulations, you have won $" + trpl);
                  amountWon += trpl;
           }


           System.out.println("Continue? Enter y = yes");
           cont = keyboard.nextLine();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Homework? Don't forget to fill in conditions for the ifs too.

Comment: @DarthJDG I suppose the `if`s are left for the next question... ]:)

Comment: my (if) I left blank as part of my question. How would I compare what the output is for each case?

Answer (score 1):

Put `a` there.  Whatever `a` is it jumps to that case in the switch statement.  Ex: if `a` is 2 it jumps to `case 2` so would print "Plum"

Could I also recommend using an Enum in this case?

```
enum SlotOptions {
   CHERRY,
   ORANGE,
   PLUM,
   BELL,
   MELON,
   BAR;
}
```

Comment: That seems logical since a is defined as `a = random.nextInt(6);`

Comment: We haven't learned enum - would I literally remove my switch and enter this text instead to have it be set to any of these pre-defined constants?

Comment: No, you would switch on the enum values instead.  It just makes it more readable, but if you haven't learned enums, maybe just wait till you get there.

Comment: Can you tell me how to improve my "if" statements?


if (0!=1)&&(0!=2)&&(0!=3)&&(0!=4)&&(0!=default)
           {
               System.out.println("You have won $0");
           }
           else if (0==1)&&(0==2)||(0==3)||(0==4)||(0==default)
           {
               System.out.println("Congratulations, you have won $" + dbl);
                  amountWon += dbl;
           }
           else if (0==1)&&(0==2)&&(0==3)||(0==4)||(0==default)
           {
               System.out.println("Congratulations, you have won $" + trpl);
                  amountWon += trpl;
           }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the swithc expression is the "actual" slow machine, so you want to put a random `int` there. Something along the lines of `switch(a)`.

Why? Think about how a slot machine works and then look at your code. The slot machine randomly picks a symbol for each spot (ie 1 fruit). In your code you have a case for each fruit. What is happening is you are representing each case with a number. So to determine which case, you need to pick a number. What number do you pick? Since its a slot machine you pick a random number. That is why you have `a=random.nextInt();`.

Comment: @PM77-1 what are you trying to say?

Comment: That in order to randomly get one of 6 possible values (from 0 to 5) we need to use `random.nextInt(6)`, i.e. with parameter.

Comment: @PM77-1 Oh, I just had that as a place holder. I edited that away a while ago.

Answer (score -2):

You don't put a test expression in a switch-statement. You put an integer value. In this case, it seems like you want a there.

Comment: (1) not only do you want to put a test expression, you NEED to put a test expression. The "int value" you refer of is the test expression in this case, because we are testing what the int value is. (2) Just sayin "an int value" isnt a good answer. What int value? Why?